# How JSONArray to String

Tags: json

Sorry my English is not good.

This Code.

```
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
JSONArray arrJSON = new JSONArray();
JSONObject aJSON = new JSONObject();

aJSON.put("1","1");
aJSON.put("2","2");
arrJSON.add(aJSON);
JSONObject sJSON = new JSONObject();
sJSON.put("A", arrJSON.toString());
return sJSON.toString();
```

this is sJSON output:

```
{"A":[{"1":"1","2":"2"}]}
```

JSONArray is not String

How do i get this?

```
{"A":"[{\"1\":\"1\",\"2\":\"2\"}]"}
```

Thx ^_^

Comment: That would be invalid JSON, to start with... you'd need the double quotes to be escaped. (Are you certain that's your exact code though? That's the output I'd expect with `json.put("A", arr_json);`. (As an aside, I'd strongly advise you to follow normal Java naming conventions in Stack Overflow questions.)

Comment: sorry, edited ^_^

Comment: I'm not sure about the library you are using, but `arrJSON.toString()` seems to be the culprit to me. Can't you use an array as input for the `put` method?

Comment: I have to test. But I don't know why.

`sJSON.put("A", arrJSON.toString());` output= `{"A":[{"1":"1","2":"2"}]}`

。
`sJSON.put("A", "n" + arrJSON.toString());` output= `{"A":"n[{\"1\":\"1\",\"2\":\"2\"}]"}`

Comment: Now I modified to manually combine JSON String.